# Understanding what a MAAS cluster can do and cant do

Tags: networking, maas, openstack, cloud

I have a cluster of 8 machines. One of the machine has 2 NICs with one connecting to the internet and the other connecting to a switch. The remaining 7 machines all have only 1 NIC each connected to the same switch. My questions are as follow:

1) If I install MAAS on the machine with 2 NICs, would it help me making the remaining 7 as a part of MAAS cluster? If yes, please advise how I should setup the IP addresses and all.

2) If by using the above method, I make all nodes a part of the same cluster, how would I be able to deploy an openstack cloud on the whole cluster? My minimum requirement is setting up an openstack cloud that allows the creation of any type of instance and uses all 8 nodes.

3) If the above 2 points are possible, how would I be able to define a particular node to be controller,compute,network,object storage, block storage node. I mean, once all nodes are a part if the same cluster, would I have to maually define a node to be any of the node mentioned above or will MAAS do this automatically?

4) Last, do I have to setup MAAS from the starting setup (similar to installing UBUNTU SERVER), or is it possible if I already have UBUNTU SERVER installed on a machine and I can install MAAS on it making it the controller node of the cluster.

I hope I am giving an idea about what I would like to do.

Answer (score 0):

1) It depends on whether you need that cluster to be open to the world.  If that is the case, you can either make the switch your "uplink" (plug you r outside network into the switch), or you can set up the MAAS server as a proxy for the other machines.  The simplest way to only connect your maas server to the outside world and make it a proxy for the internal network.  Then you can handle the IP addresses by making the cluster network managed by maas, and have maas serve as the dns and dhcp.  Since the

2) Again, it depends.  You can either then configure them by hand, or use juju to do the provisioning with various "charms" - I think there are a few threads, if you do a search with maas, juju and openstack.

3) If you use juju, you are able to define the requirements for the machines that run each of your services,  You can also force a charm to deploy to a particular machine.

4) You can start from a loaded ubuntu machine, server or desktop (I've done both).  The MAAS server machine is not run very hard, other than when it is pushing the OS out across the network, which only happens when you allocate a machine to a juju service (if you are using juju).

Comment: Your answer was very helpful.
From your answer to 1, Here is what I understand:

Connect the internet to one of the cards on the machine with 2 NICs. Connect the second NIC card to a swith. Connect remaining 7 machines to the same switch. Statically define IP's on both the interfaces on the machine with 2 NICs(public on one, private on the other). Remaining 7 machines should belong to the same private ip pool.

Comment: According to the link http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack, each machine requires 2 drives. I have a total of 8 machines but all with a single drive. I believe if I proceed with the instructions in the link, I wont be able to get landscape but I can still deploy an openstack cloud. For that, what option do i choose when it asks me to select landscape auto pilot etc etc. Also, what can be the possible twists and turns I might have to go through which are not mentioned in the link?

Comment: The machine with 2 NICs should have the NIC to the outside set to DHCP. Probably. This depends on how that external network is set up.  I don't know enough (anything) about openstack to say anything about the two drive requirement.

Comment: BTW if you like it, vote it up.  That is the life blood of stack exchange :)